# Gradle. Узнать версию библиотеки на Github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, gradle

Я использую Gradle в AndroidStudio, загрузка библиотеки выглядит следующим образом
compile 'com.aaa.bbb:ccc:0.0.0'

Откуда брать версию библиотеки, то есть 0.0.0 ?

Comment: А откуда появилось "compile 'com.aaa.bbb:ccc:0.0.0"?

Comment: @Ksenia это пример загрузки библиотеки

Comment: ну обычно стоит использовать последнюю версию, самую актуальную =)

Comment: @Ksenia мой вопрос в том, как получить эту последнюю версию, актуальную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать сервис [Gradle Please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) или искать необходимую информацию на сайте / в файле `Readme.MD` библиотеки.

[Gradle Please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) использует поиск по [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/) и если архивы библиотеки не хранятся в нём, то и найти ничего не удастся (актуально для библиотек использующих [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) публикацию)